# How to use currying?

Tags: coconut

I am playing with [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/). In my code, I would like to write apply a function on each item of a list. In Coconut, like in Python, I can write:

```
square = map(x -> x ** 2, [1,2,3]) |> list
square |> print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/v7iwNLEoVcFWITexQKNCQddOoUJBS0vBSEch2lDHSMc4VlOhxk4hJ7O4hAuqFMgtKMrMA@oFAA)

As a functional language, I expect to be able to use currying. For example in F#, this will work as expected:

```fs
let square = [1;2;3] |> List.map(fun x -> x * x)
square |> printfn "%A"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Pye1RKG4sDSxKFXBViHa0NrI2jhWocZOwSezuEQvN7FAI600T6FCQdcOSGgpVGhyQRUDlRQUZeaVpOUpKKk6Kv3/DwA)

I have the following error when I try:

```fs
square = [1,2,3] |> map(x -> x ** 2) |> list
square |> print
```

error:

```fs
TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/v7iwNLEoVcFWIdpQx0jHOFahxk4hN7FAo0JB106hQkFLS8FIEySWk1lcwgVVDOQWFGXmAXUDAA)

The message is clear. `map()` did not receive the second argument. How to use currying in Coconut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [Coconut's documentation](https://coconut.readthedocs.io/en/master/DOCS.html?highlight=curry#partial-application) has an entry about currying (also named Partial application). It is possible. From the documentation:

> Coconut uses a `$` sign right after a function’s name but before the open parenthesis used to call the function to denote partial application.
>
> Coconut’s partial application also supports the use of a `?` to skip partially applying an argument, deferring filling in that argument until the partially-applied function is called. This is useful if you want to partially apply arguments that aren’t first in the argument order.
>
> example:
>
> ```
> expnums \= range(5) |> map$(pow$(?, 2))
> expnums |> list |> print
> ```

In your case, you can write:

```
square = [1,2,3] |> map$(x -> x ** 2) |> list
square |> print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/v7iwNLEoVcFWIdpQx0jHOFahxk4hN7FARaNCQddOoUJBS0vBSBMkmJNZXMIFVQ3kFhRl5gG1AwA)